# Can we control the Zoom Level when we click on the cluster in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

Below is the JSfiddle link, Could someone help me on the below highcharts. I need to control the zoom level when user clicks on the cluster

```
 ***https://jsfiddle.net/38ahfejy/9/***
```

Comment: You can change [cluster.layoutAlgorithm](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mappoint.cluster.layoutAlgorithm) and try to adjust e.g distance.  What exactly do you want to set?

> Options for layout algorithm. Inside there are options to change the
> type of the algorithm, gridSize, distance or iterations.


https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mappoint.cluster.layoutAlgorithm

Answer (score 0):

You can change [cluster.layoutAlgorithm](https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mappoint.cluster.layoutAlgorithm) and try to adjust e.g distance.  What exactly do you want to set?

> Options for layout algorithm. Inside there are options to change the
> type of the algorithm, gridSize, distance or iterations.

https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mappoint.cluster.layoutAlgorithm